# Kivy RstDocument center aligns all its content

Tags: python, kivy, restructuredtext

I am using kivy's (2.0.0.rc3) RstDocument and for some reason it center aligns all its content.  If I set text to 'hello' it is centered (horizontally). A normal paragraphs all text are center aligned. A table, all cells are centered (though maybe that's normal). A :: block all text also centered, but it uses monospace font so it recognizes the ::

```
<Container>:
    id: container
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: '3sp'
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: (330/360, 1, 0.1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    # other components left out

    Popup:
        id: popup
        on_parent: if self.parent == container: container.remove_widget(self)
        auto_dismiss: True
        RstDocument:
            id: rst
            text: 'hello\n\nthere'
```

Python code simply call the popup's open() with no change.  Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: The `Popup` base class is `AnchorLayout` (which centers its content by default), so you might be able to add `anchor_x` and/or `anchor_y` to the `Popup` rule to adjust that behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it did nothing. I thought maybe it was because I had it in a popup and pulled it out and put it in a different container but the result was same. Odd. The kivy catalog example does not seem to be doing anything different yet it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had this

```
<Label>:
    # some properties I want all labels to have
    halign: 'center'
```

D'oh! This innocuous looking bit of code was screwing it all up!